# How to get CSS Bootstrap to render correctly in IE when not using <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I have a phone system that uses IE to view pages. In order for the phone system to work correctly I can't use `IE=Edge`, `IE=11`, or `IE=10` in the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">`

When I remove the IE=edge from the content CSS bootstrap does not render correctly.

Any idea on how can I get CSS bootstrap to render with no issues without using IE=Edge?

Comment: What do you mean by "phone system"? Are you using a Windows Phone? If so, which version of Internet Explorer are you viewing? Lastly, what is the resource you're viewing - you may be falling into quirks mode. There is also an `x-ua-compatible` response header option, if the tag is undesirable.

Comment: @Sampson it is a telephony system where people can communicate with their phone from. Then can dial number answer phone call.... isn't `x-ua-compatible` is what I am using? I am not using Windows Phone. I am using Windows Server 2008 or Windows 7 to use the phone system. I am not sure what you mean by the resource that I am viewing. if you mean the site it is a php app that uses HTML 5

Comment: We'll need quite a bit more information. Please try to answer my previous questions in your post above.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research on this subject (a few months ago actually) `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` enables the browser compatibility to modern versions of IE. <-- That may not be the textbook answer, so take it as a layman's term sort of definition. Now, the problem with removing the compatibility is that you are removing the browser's ability to read your media queries.

According to [this source](http://www.telegraphicsinc.com/2013/10/using-bootstrap-3-with-internet-explorer-8-ie8/), by including the javascript file provided in [***this link***](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/css3-mediaqueries/0.1/css3-mediaqueries.min.js), you will be able to display Bootstrap without the Compatibility meta tag and get access to the media queries again.

Disclaimer: This is not a tested solution (I don't have the environments to do so), but I did see some favorable feedback.